# Creating a Cross Tab Query

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create some sort of cross tab query to summarize how our demographic race data exists.  The table was structured to have 5 race columns (race1, race2, race3, race4, race5).  The goal is to show how many individuals fit into a different groups so for example someone who has a value in any of those fields of AS, what other (if any) groups do they also belong to.

Here's how the table is basically structured

```
Person_ID   Race1   Race2   Race3   Race4   Race5
815543      WH      BA      IN      UN      UN
815861      WH      HP      AS      UN      UN
823438      WH      BA      IN      UN      UN
825103      WH      BA      AS      UN      UN
825202      BA      WH      IN      UN      UN
825744      IN      WH      BA      UN      UN
```

This is an example the expected end result

```
        AS      BA      HP      IN      UN      WH
AS      1223    354     165     61      32216   1950
BA      823     112     264     731     119639  6135
HP      96      61      107     63      25510   285
IN      150     555     36      1000    63014   1510
UN      160     499     95      72      179927  3893
WH      2617    6012    477     1647    667126  125000
```

I'm guessing I should unpivot the data first so I have a record per race but then I'm not sure what I should try next.

Comment: would this not be easier with a reporting tool such as SSRS or the like and use a matrix to show this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then this is a pretty easy calculation when you have a fixed number of races.

This query would return what you are looking :

```
declare @RACES TABLE (RACE varchar(16))
insert into @RACES (RACE) values ('AS'), ('BA'), ('HP'), ('IN'), ('UN'), ('WH')

select RACE,
       (select count(*) 
        from MYTABLE
        where RACE in (Race1, Race2, Race3, Race4, Race5) and 
              'AS' in (Race1, Race2, Race3, Race4, Race5)) as 'AS',
       (select count(*) 
        from MYTABLE
        where RACE in (Race1, Race2, Race3, Race4, Race5) and 
              'BA' in (Race1, Race2, Race3, Race4, Race5)) as 'BA',
       (select count(*) 
        from MYTABLE
        where RACE in (Race1, Race2, Race3, Race4, Race5) and 
              'HP' in (Race1, Race2, Race3, Race4, Race5)) as 'HP',
       (select count(*) 
        from MYTABLE
        where RACE in (Race1, Race2, Race3, Race4, Race5) and 
              'IN' in (Race1, Race2, Race3, Race4, Race5)) as 'IN',
       (select count(*) 
        from MYTABLE
        where RACE in (Race1, Race2, Race3, Race4, Race5) and 
              'UN' in (Race1, Race2, Race3, Race4, Race5)) as 'UN',
       (select count(*) 
        from MYTABLE
        where RACE in (Race1, Race2, Race3, Race4, Race5) and 
              'WH' in (Race1, Race2, Race3, Race4, Race5)) as 'WH'
from @RACES
```

Although if you have a variable number of races, then you will need to dynamically build this SQL statement and launch it with sp_executesql

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/

Comment: This worked great.  Much simpler than I was trying to make it.  Thanks Marc!